# Sound Not Working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, laptop, alsa

I am a new Ubuntu user who recently downloaded 18.04 onto my (refurbished) laptop. Everything seems to work fine (although I could use some extra speed) but my audio does not work.

In the *settings > audio* tab, I don't get any inputs or outputs (not even a dummy output), but when I run

```
aplay -l
```

it seems to recognize my sound card. And, just to note, my hardware does work. It worked on Windows 10.

I have tried numerous solutions to no avail, such as:

Force reloading Alsa:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Re-installing and force-reloading Alsa:

```
sudo apt-get remove alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Renaming the hidden config directory:

```
 mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/old_pulse
```

I've tried Alsamixer instead, and, by using this command:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
```

I changed `RUN=yes` to `RUN=no.`

Again, none of these have worked and there's probably more that I've forgotten to list. So, knowing that Ubuntu can read my sound card, what do I do? Thank you!

(Edit: Output of `sudo lshw -c sound`:

"  -multimedia
       description: Multimedia controller
       product: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Imaging Unit
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
       version: 36
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi cap_list
       configuration: driver=intel_atomisp2_pm latency=0
       resources: irq:255 memory:91000000-913fffff
  *-usb:1
       description: Video
       product: USB2.0 PC CAMERA
       vendor: Generic
       physical id: 4
       bus info: usb@1:4
       version: 1.00
       capabilities: usb-2.00
       configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=256mA speed=480Mbit/s"

Comment: Please add output of the command `sudo lshw -c sound`. It will print info about the sound card(s).

Comment: Done! I added the ```sudo lshw -c sound``` output!